# Conditional variable value

Tags: c#, variables

I will try to make this simple and quick.. I have never attempted this before so I am a little lost.. What I want to do is to have a variable string (op20) that has a value based on a condition that is met.. Perhaps there is an easier way to accomplish this... Example:

```
string op20A = "5";
string op20D = "19";
string op20C = "6";
string op20E = "14";
string op20J = "15";
string op20Y = "21";

string op20raw = "R288319"

if (op20raw == "R288319") string op20 = op20A;
if (op20raw == "R288320") string op20 = op20D;
if (op20raw == "R288321") string op20 = op20C;
etc etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `switch` construct.  See here for a reference:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.80).aspx

It's always a good idea to have a `default` case, in case the variable you are testing is assigned something you hadn't explicitly set.

```
string op20A = "5";
string op20D = "19";
string op20C = "6";
string op20E = "14";
string op20J = "15";
string op20Y = "21";

string op20raw = "R288319"

// declare the string first
string op20;

// now assign it using a 'switch' statement
switch (op20raw)
{
    case "R288319":
        op20 = op20A;
        break;
    case "R288320":
        op20 = op20D;
        break;
    case "R288321":
        op20 = op20C;
        break;
    default:
        op20 = "something else";
        break;
}
```

Finally, your code would not compile because you were attempting to declare op20 three times: just declare it once then assign it as you please.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Your solution is nearly the best for just two or three conditions.

I would tend to prefer this if there are more than two or three:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "R288319", op20A },
    { "R288320", op20D },
    { "R288321", op20C }
};

string op20 = map[op20raw]; // assuming no erroneous raw strings
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are branching your code based on a single variable value (op20raw) you can use the switch statement.

For instance:

```
string op20 = String.Empty;
switch(op20raw) { 
        case "R288319": 
          op20 = op20A;
          break; 
        case "R288320": 
          op20 = op20B; 
          break; 
        // and so on
        }
```

As an alternative you can create a `Dictionary<string,string>` where the *keys* are the possible values for the op20raw variable and the *values* are the corresponding values for the op20 variable.
Then, simply get the proper value from the dictionary:

```
string a20 = myDictionary.ContainsKey(op20raw) ? myDictionary[op20raw] : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a Dictionary.

This will make your retrieval code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement:

```
switch(op20raw)
{
  case "R288319":
  op20 = op20A;
  break;
  case "R288320":
  op20 = op20D;
  break;
etc..
}
```